# python: dictionary of words and wordforms

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following problem: I created a dictionary (german) with words and their corresponding lemma. exemple:
"Lagerbestände", "Lager-bestand"; "Wohnhäuser", "Wohn-haus"; "Bahnhof", "Bahn-hof"

I now have a text and I want to check for all word their lemmata. It can happen that it appears a word which is not in the dict, such as "Restbestände". But the lemma of "bestände", we already know it. So I want to take the first part of the word which is unknown in dicti and add this to the lemmatized second part and print this out (or return it).
Example: "Restbestände" --> "Rest-bestand". ("bestand" is taken from the lemma of "Lagerbestände")

I coded the following:

```
for limit in range(1, len(Word)): 
    for k, v in dicti.iteritems():
        if re.search('[\w]*'+Word[limit:], k, re.IGNORECASE) != None:
            if '-' in v:
                tmp = v.find('-')
                end = v[tmp:]
                end = re.sub(ur'[-]',"", end)
                Word = Word[:limit] + '-' + end `
```

But I got 2 problems:

1. At the end of the words, it is printed out every time "&#10". How can I avoid this?
2. The second part of the word is sometimes not correct - there must be a logical error.

However; how would you solve this?

Comment: You should have a look at that: python Natural Language Toolkit http://nltk.org/

Comment: Please give some simple exemplary input and expected output. I have no  ida what lemma is..

Answer (score 1):

> At the end of the words, it is printed out every time "&#10". How can
>   I avoid this?

In *must* use `UNICODE` everywhere in your script. [Everywhere, everywhere, everywhere.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Also, python RegEx functions accept flag [`re.UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) that you should always set. German letters are out of ASCII set, so RegEx can be sometimes confused, for instance when matching `r'\w'`

Comment: `&#10` isn't a unicode char representation; looks like it has something to do with newlines, maybe this data comes from some HTML file?