# Wrong charset after re.sub()

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this code

```
import chardet, re    

content = "Бланк свидетельства о допуске."
print content
print chardet.detect(content)
content = re.sub(u"(?i)[^-0-9a-zа-яё«»\&\;\/\<\>\.,\s\(\)\*:!\?]", "", content)
print content
print chardet.detect(content)
```

And output

```
Бланк свидетельства о допуске.
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
� �  .
{'confidence': 0.5, 'encoding': 'windows-1252'}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get uft-8 string after `re.sub()`? 
(Python 2.7,`# coding: utf-8`, file in UTF-8, IDE Pycharm).

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to use regular expressions on raw bytes? You are operating on *bytes* here, not characters, and the input characters each consist of 2 bytes each.

Comment: And how i can get UTF-8?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16113322/497208 for a pointer to *"The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what (I think) you're trying to achieve (I've simplified the regexp for clarity):

```
#coding=utf8
import re    
content = u"Бланк XYZ свидетельства о ???допуске."
content = re.sub(u"(?iu)[^а-яё]", ".", content)
print content.encode('utf8') # Бланк.....свидетельства.о....допуске.
```

Note the important points:

- the subject is unicode
- the expression is unicode
- the expression uses the unicode flag `(?u)` to make case folding work.

Also, for serious unicode work I recommend the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module, which provides excellent and almost complete unicode support. Consider:

```
# drop everything except Cyrillic and spaces 
import regex
content = regex.sub(u'[^\p{Cyrillic}\p{Zs}]', '', content)
```

Although it's [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) that `re.UNICODE` only alters `\w` and friends, in my tests it also affects case folding (`re.IGNORECASE`):

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> src = u'Σσ Φφ Γγ'
>>> src
u'\u03a3\u03c3 \u03a6\u03c6 \u0393\u03b3'
>>> re.sub(ur'(?i)[α-ώ]', '-', src)
u'\u03a3- \u03a6- \u0393-'
>>> re.sub(ur'(?iu)[α-ώ]', '-', src)
u'-- -- --'
```

So that's either an undocumented feature or a documentation problem.

Comment: The documentation for `re.IGNORECASE` states it is not affected by locale. The `re.UNICODE` flag is documented as only altering the character classes (`\w`, `\W`, `\s`, `\S`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for `regex` module.

Comment: @thg435: Interesting, thanks for confirming! Sounds like the documentation needs updating.

Answer (score 3):

Your input is UTF-8:

```
>>> content
'\xd0\x91\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba \xd1\x81\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbe \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb5.'
```

But you are using a *unicode* regular expression. The expression is matched directly against 
the raw bytes of your UTF-8 input.

Of all those bytes, only the spaces, the full stop and the `\xbb` byte (as the `»` character), are not removed. The rest of the individual bytes are deleted, because they do not fall in your negative character class `[^...]`.

Using Unicode properly (by decoding `content` to unicode first) works:

```
>>> re.sub(u"(?i)[^-0-9a-zа-яё«»\&\;\/\<\>\.,\s\(\)\*:!\?]", "", content.decode('utf8'))
u'\u043b\u0430\u043d\u043a \u0441\u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0430 \u043e \u0434\u043e\u043f\u0443\u0441\u043a\u0435.'
>>> print re.sub(u"(?i)[^-0-9a-zа-яё«»\&\;\/\<\>\.,\s\(\)\*:!\?]", "", content.decode('utf8'))
ланк свидетельства о допуске.
```

The alternative would be to use a raw byte string for the regular expression, and matching *byte combinations*. Working out what UTF-8 bytes and ranges are valid is *very*, **very** tricky. You'll need to *fully* understand how [UTF-8 encodes characters to multiple bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), then translate your negative character class to a set of *positive* matches that allow through the same byte combinations. This is **not** for the faint of heart.

Comment: Apologies, I realize that your expression itself *is* unicode. You should not mix those.